# How to check the number of elements in the array with underscore template

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

HeIIo, I have the following array:
name: John,
email: [email@gmail.com, email2@gmail.com]

I want to represent this data differently if the number of emails is just 1 or more than 1.
So, basically, I want to check if(number_of_elements_in_email == 1), do something, else do different.

Could someone show me how to do it with underscore?
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The stuff inside `<% ... %>` in an Underscore template is just JavaScript so, if your `email` is an array then you'd say:

```
<% if(email.length === 0) { %>
    <!-- do "there are no email addresses" stuff -->
<% } else if(email.length === 1) { %>
    <!-- do "there is only one email" stuff -->
<% } else { %>
    <!-- do "there are several email addresses" stuff -->
<% } %>
```

Comment: I would recommend avoiding `==` in favor of `===`.

Comment: @Sukima Yeah, that's fair. Haven't been using plain JavaScript for awhile and my fingers have forgotten.